# Spatial query and sending SMS - Which techno on mobile?

Tags: software-recommendations, proximity, mobile, spatial-query, offline

I would like to set up a mobile application to send SMS messages to nearby contacts. To make it simple, here are the steps in the process:

1. The user opens the app and adds a point on the map.
2. A script automatically returns the list of contacts within a radius of 10 km around the point.
3. The user's smartphone sends an SMS (via SIM card) to each contact found.

The nomadic user may sometimes be out of reach of the 3G/4G network, so the data (rasters, location and number of contacts...) will have to be stored in the smartphone memory.

Which technology do you think should be used for offline use?

[image: Radius selection]

Comment: Wow interesting question... There is a geo component, but I think the main technology resides in non-geo tech, ie PHP and other scripts that can communicate to services that pick up changes in a database. I would think a postgresql/postgis back-end hooked up to *something* would be good for this... (I think the votes to 'close' are because of the mainly non-geo component to the solution... would be curious to know how this is done regardless!)